# Error in stored procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This query is raising an error:

```
DECLARE @CategoryId int
SELECT @CategoryId = 1

exec [USP_GetLimitedRecords]
        @Query = N'SELECT b.* FROM Boxes b INNER JOIN Categories c ON b.CategoryId = c.Id WHERE c.Id= ' + @CategoryId,
        @PrimaryKey = N'id',
        @PageNo = 1,
        @PageSize = 20
```

Error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '+'.

This query works

```
exec [USP_GetLimitedRecords]
        @Query = N'SELECT b.* FROM Boxes b INNER JOIN Categories c ON b.CategoryId = c.Id WHERE c.Id= 1',
        @PrimaryKey = N'id',
        @PageNo = 1,
        @PageSize = 20
```

Comment: you cannot joins strings in setting a call parameter

Comment: BTW, that looks a horrible way to solve that problem (i.e. the dynamic query passed in).

Comment: See answer dont be quick to say No. Try to find alternate or solution

Comment: I know the alternative thanks. That wasn't your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try with below query, thanks

```
DECLARE @CategoryId int
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(250)
SELECT @CategoryId = 1

SET @MyQuery = N'SELECT b.* FROM Boxes b INNER JOIN Categories c ON b.CategoryId = c.Id WHERE c.Id= ' + CAST( @CategoryId AS VARCHAR)

exec [USP_GetLimitedRecords]
        @Query = @MyQuery,
        @PrimaryKey = N'id',
        @PageNo = 1,
        @PageSize = 20
```